# How to use unicode symbols in a kableExtra HTML table

Tags: html, r, kableextra

I have the following dataframe in R

```
data <- structure(list(Category = c("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"), `Month 1` = c(-3.7, 
0.8, -2.1), `Month 2` = c(-2.1, 0.8, -3.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm using this dataframe to create a table using `kableExtra` (and ultimately rendering it in HTML format). Below, I created an extra column which uses 2 ifelse arguments (where the word "up" if Month 2 > Month 1, "down" if Month 2 < Month 1, or blank if Month 2 = Month 1). Instead of having words, I would like to use unicode symbols in this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp) to display arrows.

Is there a way to use unicode hex codes instead of words, so that I can have the North East Arrow for "Up", Rightwards arrow for the blank argument, and the South East Arrow for "down"?

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(Trend = ifelse(.[,3] > .[,2],"Up", ifelse(.[,3] == .[,2], "",  "Down"))) %>% 
  kable() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

I'm ultimately looking to replicate something along the lines of the image I've attached

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `kableExtra` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data %>%
  mutate(Trend = case_when(`Month 1` == `Month 2` ~ "$\\rightarrow$", 
                           `Month 2` > `Month 1` ~ "$\\uparrow$", 
                           TRUE ~ "$\\downarrow$")) %>%
  kable() %>% kable_styling()
```

[image]

Appropriate symbols can be found from [this pdf](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

One option is `formattable`

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
data <- data %>% 
    mutate(Trend = case_when(`Month 2` > `Month 1` ~ "Up",
      `Month 1` > `Month 2` ~ "Down", TRUE ~ "" ))


formattable(data, list(
  
  Trend = formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ style(color = case_when(x =="Up" ~ "green",
      x == "Down" ~ "red", TRUE ~ "black")),
    x ~ icontext(case_when(x == "Down"~ "arrow-down",
        x== "Up" ~ "arrow-up", TRUE ~ "arrow-right")))
))
```

-output

[image]